# Python 3 Multiprocessing and Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I have a client script that communicates with multiple servers. It appears from my testing and research that python's socket library is synchronous. No matter what I do, single socket variable or dynamic socket variables, the script will not send and receive data at the same time. Here's the basic version of my script using dynamic socket ids:

```
import socket
import logging
import os
import time
from time import time
import datetime
import multiprocessing

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

IP=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
IP[0] = '192.168.1.21'
IP[1] = '192.168.1.22'
IP[2] = '192.168.1.23'
IP[3] = '192.168.1.24'
IP[4] = '192.168.1.25'
IP[5] = '192.168.1.26'
PORT = 1292

def ClientWorker(ip, port, socketid):
            name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
            ts = time()
            s = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
            s[socketid] = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s[socketid].connect((ip, port))
            s[socketid].send(b"Get status")
            response = s[socketid].recv(50)
            s[socketid].close()
            print('Connection to {}:'.format(ip))
            print('Process Took: {}'.format(time() - ts))

def main():
    tsmain = time()
    socketnum = 0
    workers = []
    for ipaddr in IP:
        logger.info('Queueing {}'.format(ipaddr))
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=ClientWorker, args=(ipaddr, PORT, socketnum))
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
        socketnum += 1
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    print('Main Took {}'.format(time() - tsmain))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Multiprocessing output:

```
2016-07-06 10:32:17,178 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.21
2016-07-06 10:32:17,181 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.22
2016-07-06 10:32:17,181 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.23
2016-07-06 10:32:17,183 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.24
2016-07-06 10:32:17,184 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.25
2016-07-06 10:32:17,185 - __main__ - INFO - Starting 192.168.1.26
Connection to 192.168.1.22: 
Process Took 0.36358118057250977
Connection to 192.168.1.25: 
Process Took 0.37239646911621094
Connection to 192.168.1.21: 
Process Took 0.3772423267364502
Connection to 192.168.1.26: 
Process Took 0.4828777313232422
Connection to 192.168.1.24: 
Process Took 0.6024985313415527
Connection to 192.168.1.23: 
Process Took 0.7020003795623779
Main Took 0.708820104598999
```

It looks like all the processes are starting at pretty much the same time but each process takes longer to complete, which suggests only one socket can be open at once.

I've done research on twisted, asyncio & asyncore. I started going down the twisted road but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around that because the messages sent to each server will not be the same. The script will be designed to send different tasks to each server at the same time and wait for the results.

### Edit

More detailed output:

```
(0, 0) = Process-1 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.227847
(0, 1) = Process-2 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228606
(0, 2) = Process-3 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.229448
(0, 3) = Process-4 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.231957
(0, 4) = Process-5 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232951
(0, 5) = Process-6 Work started: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233697
(1, 0) = Process-1 Setting up network socket 0 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.227894
(1, 1) = Process-2 Setting up network socket 1 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228655
(1, 2) = Process-3 Setting up network socket 2 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.229498
(1, 3) = Process-4 Setting up network socket 3 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232006
(1, 4) = Process-5 Setting up network socket 4 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232994
(1, 5) = Process-6 Setting up network socket 5 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233742
(2, 0) = Process-1 Completed network socket setup 0 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228005 - took 0:00:00.000121
(2, 1) = Process-2 Completed network socket setup 1 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228781 - took 0:00:00.000137
(2, 2) = Process-3 Completed network socket setup 2 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.229608 - took 0:00:00.000120
(2, 3) = Process-4 Completed network socket setup 3 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232109 - took 0:00:00.000112
(2, 4) = Process-5 Completed network socket setup 4 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233081 - took 0:00:00.000092
(2, 5) = Process-6 Completed network socket setup 5 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233854 - took 0:00:00.000122
(3, 0) = Process-1 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228046
(3, 1) = Process-2 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228823
(3, 2) = Process-3 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.229647
(3, 3) = Process-4 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232145
(3, 4) = Process-5 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233109
(3, 5) = Process-6 Connecting to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233893
(4, 0) = Process-1 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232009 - took 0:00:00.003983
(4, 1) = Process-2 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232624 - took 0:00:00.003818
(4, 2) = Process-3 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233706 - took 0:00:00.004080
(4, 3) = Process-4 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.235946 - took 0:00:00.003827
(4, 4) = Process-5 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.236215 - took 0:00:00.003120
(4, 5) = Process-6 Connected to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.237408 - took 0:00:00.003530
(5, 0) = Process-1 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228046
(5, 1) = Process-2 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.228823
(5, 2) = Process-3 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.229647
(5, 3) = Process-4 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232145
(5, 4) = Process-5 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233109
(5, 5) = Process-6 Beginning to send data to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233893
(6, 0) = Process-1 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232084 - took 0:00:00.000038
(6, 1) = Process-2 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232699 - took 0:00:00.000039
(6, 2) = Process-3 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233788 - took 0:00:00.000044
(6, 3) = Process-4 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.236024 - took 0:00:00.000035
(6, 4) = Process-5 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.236263 - took 0:00:00.000023
(6, 5) = Process-6 Completed data send to network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.237456 - took 0:00:00.000022
(7, 0) = Process-1 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232102
(7, 1) = Process-2 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.232717
(7, 2) = Process-3 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.233809
(7, 3) = Process-4 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.236041
(7, 4) = Process-5 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.236274
(7, 5) = Process-6 Beginning to wait for data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.237467
(8, 0) = Process-1 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.273043 - took 0:00:00.040980
(8, 1) = Process-2 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.277420 - took 0:00:00.044757
(8, 2) = Process-3 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.267754 - took 0:00:00.033984
(8, 3) = Process-4 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.281372 - took 0:00:00.045383
(8, 4) = Process-5 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.278337 - took 0:00:00.042100
(8, 5) = Process-6 Received data from network socket @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.197792 - took 0:00:00.960364
(9, 0) = Process-1 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.273101
(9, 1) = Process-2 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.277494
(9, 2) = Process-3 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.267812
(9, 3) = Process-4 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.281444
(9, 4) = Process-5 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.278390
(9, 5) = Process-6 Beginning to process response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.197861
(10, 0) = Process-1 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.273140 - took 0:00:00.000048
(10, 1) = Process-2 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.277529 - took 0:00:00.000043
(10, 2) = Process-3 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.267847 - took 0:00:00.000045
(10, 3) = Process-4 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.281475 - took 0:00:00.000038
(10, 4) = Process-5 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.278418 - took 0:00:00.000035
(10, 5) = Process-6 Finished processing response from server @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.197889 - took 0:00:00.000035
(11, 0) = Process-1 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.273156
(11, 1) = Process-2 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.277544
(11, 2) = Process-3 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.267865
(11, 3) = Process-4 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.281488
(11, 4) = Process-5 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.278432
(11, 5) = Process-6 Communicating with server to retreive additional information @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.197903
(12, 0) = Process-1 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.848586 - took 0:00:00.575468
(12, 1) = Process-2 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.637331 - took 0:00:01.359825
(12, 2) = Process-3 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.765458 - took 0:00:00.497645
(12, 3) = Process-4 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.541048 - took 0:00:01.259597
(12, 4) = Process-5 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.818199 - took 0:00:00.539810
(12, 5) = Process-6 Finished final retreival of data @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.526207 - took 0:00:00.328342
(13, 0) = Process-1 Closing network socket 0 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.848643
(13, 1) = Process-2 Closing network socket 1 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.637387
(13, 2) = Process-3 Closing network socket 2 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.765536
(13, 3) = Process-4 Closing network socket 3 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.541101
(13, 4) = Process-5 Closing network socket 4 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.818264
(13, 5) = Process-6 Closing network socket 5 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.526262
(14, 0) = Process-1 Closed network socket 0 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.848719 - took 0:00:00.000086
(14, 1) = Process-2 Closed network socket 1 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.637463 - took 0:00:00.000086
(14, 2) = Process-3 Closed network socket 2 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.765647 - took 0:00:00.000128
(14, 3) = Process-4 Closed network socket 3 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.541168 - took 0:00:00.000075
(14, 4) = Process-5 Closed network socket 4 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:02.818365 - took 0:00:00.000114
(14, 5) = Process-6 Closed network socket 5 @ 2016-07-06 15:42:03.526333 - took 0:00:00.000080
(15, 0) = Process-1 Took 0:00:00.620923
(15, 1) = Process-2 Took 0:00:01.408908
(15, 2) = Process-3 Took 0:00:00.536262
(15, 3) = Process-4 Took 0:00:01.309261
(15, 4) = Process-5 Took 0:00:00.585469
(15, 5) = Process-6 Took 0:00:01.292729
(16, 0) = Process-1 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.848763
(16, 1) = Process-2 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:03.637487
(16, 2) = Process-3 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.765685
(16, 3) = Process-4 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:03.541191
(16, 4) = Process-5 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:02.818397
(16, 5) = Process-6 Work finished: 2016-07-06 15:42:03.526357
Main Took 0:00:01.430665
```

Comment: Can you get corresponding log-information from each of the servers that you're pinging? Also,why not also measure the amount of time ... and maybe capture the time-stamp ... that is spent *sending* the reply, separate from the time spent waiting for and receiving the reply. In both cases, print the actual time values, as well as the deltas between them.

Comment: @mike-robinson I've edited my question with more detailed output. It looks like each process may have it's own socket after all. Is it your assertion that it's a server that's taking longer to respond?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't "assert" anything ... (how *could* I?) ... All that I can hope to do is to point your future wanderings into a possibly-fruitful direction. **:-)**

Comment: @mike-robinson Yeah, poor choice of words. Thanks for your tips. It would appear that multiple sockets are being created and used almost simultaneously. I'll dig into the server side of things and see what's up.

Comment: I don't know if you dispatched to different IP-addresses purposely or just for the sake of the example you posted here. If they truly are different (and the IP-addresses all map to really-different hardware), I'm surprised by the results obtained. A good possibility here is that there is some common resource ... a database, perhaps, or a database connection ... access to which is being serialized. Basically, "resource contention."

Comment: @mike-robinson The multiple addresses is on purpose. The ultimate goal is to send different tasks to different machines/end-points at the same time compiled the results at a single source, my client app. Then, new jobs based on the results will be resent to those end-points for more tasks. I was surprised too. There's nothing in common with those machines except they are in VMware. There's no reported resource constraints on the host or cluster. I'll have to look at the endpoints nonetheless. The box running the client app is a i5 dual core dedicated Ubuntu LTS box. Any issues there?

Comment: Can't obviously see any reasons for what you are seeing. Having both the client the server attach their own timestamps (*"this is the instant that I received this request" ... this is the instant that I sent the reply"*) to the round-trip packet might shed some light. It *does* still smell like some kind of "common shared resource" issue: something that basically caused the requests to "stand in line," possibly on the remote side. Something that, although they are five separate machines, they all had to share to get the job done . . .

Comment: @mike-robinson Cool. Thanks for everything Mike. If I find the culprit, I'll update everyone.

Comment: I'll be listening for that ***"d'oh!"***  I'm sure we'll all be able to hear it.  *;-)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did indeed find out that my original code is good and that the discrepancies in timing were the result of the end machines being busy with other tasks or just slow to respond in general.